# Connecting to a specific database using FreeTDS

Tags: centos, freetds, unixodbc

I have my `freetds.conf` set up thusly. Notice that I specifically have set up the database as myawesomedb:

```
[EXAMPLE_CONF]
driver = /usr/lib64/libtdsodbc.so
host = example.org
database = myawesomedb
port = 5150
tds version = 8.0
;client charset = UTF-8
```

Similarly, I've set up the `odbc.ini` like so:

```
[EXAMPLE_CONF]
Description = SQL Server 2005
Driver      = FreeTDS
Database   = myawesomedb
Servername  = EXAMPLE_CONF
TDS_Version    = 8.0
```

However when I connect using tsql, it seems to ignore that I've set the database:

```
$ tsql -S EXAMPLE_CONF -U jordan
locale is "en_US.UTF-8"
locale charset is "UTF-8"
Password: 
1> select db_name()
2> go

master
```

This is what I want to happen:

```
$ tsql -S EXAMPLE_CONF -U jordan
locale is "en_US.UTF-8"
locale charset is "UTF-8"
Password: 
1> select db_name()
2> go

myawesomedb
```

I assume I'm just missing something in the configuration?

Here is the relevant version info:

FreeTDS
version: 0.64
release: 11.el5.centos

unixODBC:
version: 2.2.11
release: 7.1